# i want to send a request to the backend when clicking a radio button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I use React.js.
The name of the room assigned to each home appliance
is get from the backend and displayed.
The room to which the home appliance belongs is checked as an initial value with a radio button.

[image]

What I want to achieve is
When I click a different radio button
I want to send a request to the backend with handleChange

**Issue/error message**

The request is not sent when I click a different radio button.
I don't see anything in the console either.
I don't know why...

```
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const DropDownForRoomChangeButton = (item) => {

  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
  
  const handleChange = e => {
    setVal(e.target.name);
    setDeviceRoomName(e.target.name);
  }

  const setDeviceRoomName = async(data) => {
    console.log("Body sent to server", {
      attributes: 
      [
        {
          entity_id : item.item.entity_id, 
          room_name: data
        }
    ]
    })
    await axios.post('xxx.com',
      {
          attributes: 
          [
            {
              entity_id : item.item.entity_id, 
              room_name: data
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
        console.log(entity_id);
        console.log('Set Device Room Name!');
        getDevices();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(entity_id);
        console.log('Missed Set Device Room Name!');
      });
  }

  const getDevices = async(data) => {
    await axios.get('xxx.com',
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
        setDevices(result.data.attributes);  
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }


  const keys = [
    "camera",
    "climate",
    "cover",
    "light",
    "lock",
    "sensor",
    "switch",
  ];

  const entities = keys
    .map((key) => (devices[key] || []).map((e) => ({ ...e, key })))
    .flat();

  const roomNames = [...new Set(entities.map((entity) => entity.room_name))];


  const [val, setVal] = useState();
  console.log(val)
  const HomeHandleChange = e => setVal(e.target.value);

  const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ children, onClick }, ref) => (
    <a
    href=""
    ref={ref}
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick(e);
    }}
  >
    {children}
    <button className="btn btn-primary button_table_rightside">Unassigned</button>
  </a>
  ));

useEffect(() => {
  getDevices();
  setVal(item.item.room_nam)
},[]);

console.log(roomNames)
console.log(item)
console.log(item.item.room_name)

  return (
    <>

                    
                    <Dropdown className="room_change_dropdown_top">

                    <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle} id="dropdown-custom-components" />

                      <Dropdown.Menu className="room_change_dropdown">
                        <Dropdown.Item className="room_change_dropdown_item">
                          {roomNames.map((room_names, i) => (
                            <div className="flex_radio">
                              <input
                                className="room_change_radio"
                                type="radio"
                                value={room_names}
                                name={item.item.room_name}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                checked={val === item.item.room_name}
                              />
                              <p className="drop_down_p">{room_names}</p>
                            </div>
                            ))}
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                      </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown>




    </>
  );
}
export default DropDownForRoomChangeButton;
```

Comment: which version of react and react-bootstrap you use ?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0", "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0","axios": "^0.27.2",

Comment: ```const handleChange = (e) =>``` try bounding e with ().

Comment: thank you but nothing in cosole

Comment: access this link and modify your data roomNames for me and send back. Lets find out why it not running https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-radio-button-example-forked-t11tpr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: sorry I can't write whole code there but wierd thing is I comment out "checked={val === item.item.room_name}", I can see console but I need checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
                      <input
                        className="room_change_radio"
                        type="radio"
                        value={room_names}
                        name={room_names}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        checked={val === room_names}
                      />
```

works